# What are the odds that my sister and I share birth dates with Lennon & McCartney

Tags: probability

My birth date, 6/18/69, is the same as Paul McCartney's (6/18/42).

My sister's birth date, 10/9/70, is the same as John Lennon's (10/9/40 - a leap year).

We are curious to know what the odds/probability of such an occurrence is and would appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: Given a non-leap year, the probability that on said year two people are born on the dates you mention is $\frac{2}{365^2}$.

Comment: @Anguepa, well that's assuming a random child is equally likely to be born on any day of the year, but that's surely not the case

Comment: Those dates should be 18/6/42 and 9/10/40 if you must write them in that format (Liverpool, where the gentlemen in question were born, is in England, where we write dates as DAY/MONTH/YEAR). The answer to your question about probabilities depends on what you mean by "such an occurrence": e.g., if you are talking about living individuals (like you and your sister) at some point in time, the chances of a pair of living individuals having the same pair of birthdays as Lennon and McCartney was zero before 9th October 1940, is non-zero now and will return to zero in 30 or 40 years.

Comment: The question needs some clarification.  Are you asking the odds that you would both share a birthday with a famous person? Are you asking the odds that you would both share a birthday with a Beatle?  Are you asking the odds that a brother and sister somewhere share birthdays with John and Paul?  If you're asking the odds that you share Paul's birthday and you're sister share's Johns, we know the probability is 1 because you have already told us that you share Paul's birthday and you're sister share's Johns.

Comment: It would help to know how much you want the answer to address leap years. Is it ok to ignore them entirely?  Just treat them as happening every four years?  Include the fact that sometimes leap years get skipped on century marks?

Comment: I am grateful to all who took the time to respond. I also was reminded of the importance of properly stating the question as math makes no assumptions (or cannot, in this instance). Again -- THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

If you pick two pairs of people at random and want to know if the first pair shares birthdays with the second pair, ignoring leap years, the probability is 
$$
\frac{1}{365} *\frac{1}{365}*\frac{1}{365} +\frac{364}{365}*\frac{2}{365}*\frac{1}{365}
$$

There are two terms added together.  The first represents the probability that the first pair (call them John and Paul) were born on the same day and that the other pair (you and your sister) were also born on that day.  This is calculated as follows.  The probability that John was born on a day in the year is 1, so we can ignore that.  The probability that Paul was born on the same day is 1/365. The probability of you being born on that day is also 1/365. And the probability of your sister being born that day is 1/365.  Multiply those together and you get the probability that all four of you were born on the same day.

The second term shows the odds that John and Paul were born on different days and that you and your sister share those days.  Again, John's probability of being born on a day of the year is 1 so we can ignore that. Paul's probability of being born on a different day is 364/365.  Your probability of being born on one of those two days is 2/365. Your sister's probability of being born on the other of those two days is 1/365.